# Why a function is treated as a class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm on "Introducing ES2015" course of Treehouse and the teacher shows this code to illustrate the arrow functions but here he instantiates the function as a class. Can anybody tell me how is it possible?

What I learned about objects is that you need to create a class before to instantiate it or create a literal object which is not this case.

```
'use strict';

var Person = function(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        this[key] = data[key];
    }
    this.getKeys = () => {
        return Object.keys(this);
    }
}
var Alena = new Person({ name: 'Alena', role: 'Teacher' });

console.log('Alena\s Keys: ', Alena.getKeys()); // 'this' refers to 'Alena'

var getKeys = Alena.getKeys;

console.log(getKeys());
```

Everything works but I don't know why.

Comment: If I say `class` just creates a function ... then I do confuse you even more right? ;)

Comment: You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions for a comprehensive explanation of what functions really are in JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) and [What is return new function(); in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178701) and [What are all the differences between function and constructor function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401553)

Comment: What @JonasWilms is saying, it's `Class` doesn't really exist in javascript. The transpilation of `class Person {}` in ES will be what your teacher has writen :)

Comment: I'm not qualified to give a proper answer but it's basically a combination of how JavaScript implements object-oriented programming (it's a prototype-based language rather than a class-based one), the fact that functions are objects in JavaScript and the syntax choice of the guys who created the language. IMHO is not the most intuitive language to learn OOP.

Comment: That's how you wrote constructor functions before `class` was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask yourself one question: What is a `class` really?

Actually it is just a syntax to compose the following things:

1) A `constructor`. That is some kind of function, that constructs an instance of the class.

2) methods. They can be called *on* instances.

Now for the second one, JS has already a great feature to achieve this: Prototypal Inheritance. Objects can inherit other objects, including methods:

```
  const proto = { method() { /*...*/ } };

  const instance = Object.create(proto);
  instance.method(); // that works, as instance inherits proto
```

Now we only need constructors, for that we could just call a function after we created an object using the method above:

```
   constructInstance(Object.create(proto));
```

Now as that is quite a common task (as JS has prototypal inheritance from the beginning), the `new` operator was added, which basically does all that:

1) It creates an empty object inheriting from `.prototype` of the function called on.

2) It calls the function itself with `this` being the object.

3) It gives back that object.

```
   function Person(name) {
     this.name = name;
   }

   Person.prototype.method = function() { /*...*/ };

  new Person("Jonas").method();
```

And there you go, inheritance & constructors without any `class`es.

Now as that is still no quite beautiful, the `class` syntax was added, which basically just creates a function with a prototype.